# How to convert string to Integer and add it arrayList

Tags: java, string, arraylist

How can I convert the string to Integers and how can I create an ArrayList with these integers?
My String contains only numbers and there is a gap between my numbers.
For example, given the string `st1 = "1 2 3 4"` or `str2 = "11 20 23 24"`.
I need an `ArrayList for str1` like `"1, 2, 3, 4"`
I tried to use `Integer.parseInt(str1)` and `Integer.valueOf(str1)` but these work for such as `str1 = "1234"`

Comment: So do you need to convert `st1 = "1 2 3 4"` to `st1 = "1234"` first?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This method will convert such strings to an `ArrayList<Integer>`:

```
public static ArrayList<Integer> toStringList(String string){
    String ints[]=string.split(" ");
    ArrayList<Integer> list=new ArrayList<>();
    for(String str:ints){
        list.add(Integer.parseInt(str));
    }
}
```

Remember this method will convert your string such as "1 2 3 4" to a list with 1 to 4 values. If you want to convert it to `1234` you should first remove the spaces:

```
String str="1 2  3 4  ";
str = str.replaceAll(" ","");
Integer number=Integer.parseInt(str); //equals 1234
```

Comment: Better to use `replace` as this is not using regex `str = str.replace(" ","");`

Comment: Thank you, the first answered my question and it works. How can I do that without using `String ints[]=string.split(" "); ` , so in a way, without using array?

Comment: If you want the numbers to be seperate you have to split the string

Answer (score 1):

You could do so to convert a list of strings to integers. Following @Tim code

```
        String st1 = "1 2 3 4";
        String[] array = st1.split("\\s+");
        List<Integer> integers = Arrays.stream(array)
                .map(Integer::valueOf).collect(Collectors.toList());
        System.out.println(integers);
        //[1, 2, 3, 4]
```

Answer (score 0):

This code will convert any number found within the string to its integer. This will solve your problem.

```
String str = "1 2 3 4 5 11 12 13 14 15 1 12 123 1234 12345";
int stringLength = str.length();
int[] answer;
String intBuffer = "";
int j = 0, countSpaces = 0;

for (int i = 0; i < stringLength; i++) {
    if (str.charAt(i) == ' ') countSpaces++;
}
answer = new int[countSpaces + 1];

for (int i = 0; i < stringLength; i++) {
    if (str.charAt(i) != ' ') {
        intBuffer = intBuffer + str.charAt(i);
        if (i == stringLength - 1)
            answer[j] = Integer.parseInt(intBuffer);
    } else {
        answer[j++] = Integer.parseInt(intBuffer);
        intBuffer = "";
    }
}
for (int i = 0; i < answer.length; i++)
    System.out.println(answer[i] + " ");
```